# How can I create a PDF in Ruby from an array of images with different page sizes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, rmagick, minimagick

I'm generating labels to print, which need to be sent in PDF format. The printer has a cutter, so it's beneficial to have each page only as long as it needs to be so as not to waste the label, which is a continuous length.

I generate a PDF using wkhtmltopdf (as a background job) and then split the pages into PNGs. Each image has the unused portion cropped off the bottom. I'd like to combine the images back into a PDF.

If anyone has any sample code using rghost, minimagick or rmagick, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would a job for Origami

[https://github.com/gdelugre/origami/blob/master/README.md](https://github.com/gdelugre/origami)

> Origami is a pure Ruby library to parse, modify and generate PDF documents.

I did not test it myself, but it's made for this kind of job. I wonder about the performances too.